# Are there any useful tools / techniques for creating website content inventories?

Tags: hierarchy, taxonomy, inventory

This is probably wishful thinking but here goes...

Now obviously I don't expect some magical app to crawl a website, summarise each page and detail all the assets within each page (if only!) however **is there a crawler of some sort that will trawl a given website and produce a full set of links and respective hierarchy** would be invaluable. That would ensure that no pages get missed out as they invariably would through a purely manual inventory.

From there I would be able to see the existing site hierarchies and taxonomy decisions that have been made when building the site, and could use this as the basis for creating a detailed website content inventory.

Whether this be an online application, script or even a useful manual technique other than just manually sitting at the site and following links would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Website Auditor](http://www.link-assistant.com/website-auditor/) is a tool that crawls your site and delivers a nested hierarchy, complete with meta info, broken link information, error codes, etc.  We've found it VERY useful for the exact purposes that you list.

Alternatively, I've used [Site Sucker](http://www.sitesucker.us/mac/mac.html) for Mac (which is free) to download a local copy of an entire site, and used the log file as my content inventory.  However, it's not as useful because it doesn't generate a nested view nor any of the niceties previously mentioned for Website Auditor, so it's definitely a "poor man's tool".